# 2D FFT of an image shows some invalid values for high frequencies

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, fft, windowing

I uploaded my 2D FFT magnitude image here:

[image]

If you take a look at it, for high frequencies[right, left, top and bottom], only at around x and y-axis, there are some points with high power[yellow color]. These points shouldn't be in the resultant FFT2, since I know the original height image is isotropic and therefore the 2D FFT must look  something like the example below(just note high frequencies):

[image]

Now, the question is, what could be the possible reasons for such behavior at high frequencies?

added:
Here is the magnitude power spectrum before windowing:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82779497/nowin.png

here is the original image, which is a height profile recorded by a profilometer:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82779497/asph5.jpg

By the way, I export data as a `.txt` file from profilometer software to Matlab.

Comment: I think, that's an edge-effect. What are you using for FFT?

Comment: I'm using fft2 in Matlab. Using fftshift, zero padding and window function. I used and tried any possible window functions: tuketywin, hann, triangular window,.. but they don't work. The first uploaded picture is after being windowed by win=tukeywin(n,0.25)*tukeywin(m,0.25)';

Comment: Can you show original image?

Comment: It could be quantization/truncation noise or other artefacts from your image capture.

Comment: Thankss for your answer, I added the information to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profilometer we use for capturing the surface image, uses fringe projection method which produces some artifacts along the projected stripes on the surface. So, the problem lies on the device we are capturing images with.

Thanks for comments Eddy.